# I have 2 weapon slots of the same type, but when i click items of weapon type only 1 slot gets occupied

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an inventory system with 4 types of equipment using

```
public enum EquipmentType
{
    Weapon,
    Head,
    Body,
    Feet,
}
```

but I have 5 slots (2 slots for weapon). I have implemented RightClick Event (Right clicking items in inventory will equip the items to respective slots in the equipment panel). So when I right click items of type weapon, only one slot gets occupied.
Also I have implemented drag and drop methods which seems to be working fine for the both the slots. the following are the scripts that I used.

EquipmentSlot.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EquipmentSlot : ItemSlot
{ 
    public EquipmentType EquipmentType;
    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
        base.OnValidate();
        gameObject.name = EquipmentType.ToString() + " Slot";
    }

    public override bool CanRecieveItem(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return true;

        EquippableItem equippableItem = item as EquippableItem;
        return equippableItem != null && equippableItem.EquipmentType == EquipmentType;
    }
```

EquipmentPanel.cs

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class EquipmentPanel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EquipmentSlot[] EquipmentSlots;
    [SerializeField] Transform equipmentSlotsParent;

    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnRightClickEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerEnterEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerExitEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnBeginDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnEndDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDropEvent;


    public void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < EquipmentSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += OnRightClickEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += OnPointerEnterEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += OnPointerExitEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += OnBeginDragEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += OnEndDragEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnDragEvent += OnDragEvent;
            EquipmentSlots[i].OnDropEvent += OnDropEvent;
        }
    }
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        EquipmentSlots = equipmentSlotsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<EquipmentSlot>();
    }
    public bool AddItem(EquippableItem item, out EquippableItem previousItem)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < EquipmentSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            if(EquipmentSlots[i].EquipmentType == item.EquipmentType)
            {
                previousItem = (EquippableItem)EquipmentSlots[i].Item;
                EquipmentSlots[i].Item = item;
                return true;
            }
        }
        previousItem = null;
        return false;
    }
    public bool RemoveItem(EquippableItem item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < EquipmentSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (EquipmentSlots[i].Item == item)
            {
                EquipmentSlots[i].Item = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddItem()` method finds the **first** slot of the type `EquipmentType.Weapon` and replaces it with the item you are trying to add.

If you have 2 slots of type `EquipmentType.Weapon` as you said, this means that `AddItem()` will **always** replace the **first** found slot, and **never even touch the second slot**.

This could be a possible way of doing it:

```
public bool AddItem(EquippableItem item, out EquippableItem previousItem)
{
    int lastFoundSlotIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0; i < EquipmentSlots.Length; i++)
    {
        if(EquipmentSlots[i].EquipmentType == item.EquipmentType)
        {
            lastFoundSlotIndex = i;

            if (EquipmentSlots[i].Item == null)
                break;
        }
    }

    if (lastFoundSlotIndex >= 0)
    {
        previousItem = (EquippableItem)EquipmentSlots[lastFoundSlotIndex].Item;
        EquipmentSlots[lastFoundSlotIndex].Item = item;
        return true;
    }

    previousItem = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so what would be a better code to fix this issue?

Comment: This depends on what you intend to do when both slots are occupied. I have added the code for a solution which first tries to find an empty slot to fit the weapon. If no slots are available, it replaces the weapon in the second found slot by the weapon you are trying to equip.

Comment: I tried changing my code but it does not seem to work. It gives me a totally different output (Replacing items in inventory with previously clicked items).

Comment: I'm sorry, I got a wrong index in `EquipmentSlots[i].Item = item;`. It should be `EquipmentSlots[lastFoundSlotIndex].Item = item;`. The code is fixed now.